# Connecting Django to postgresql

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geodjango, django

I plan on building a web application using Geodjango. After installing PostgreSQL, PostGIS, OsGeo4W and psycopg. I changed my settings.py db to that of the PostGIS. Each time I run the commmad "python manage.py runserver" I get the error "api-ms-win-crt-heap-|1-1-0.dll is missing."

i have kb299261 installed and microsoft visual  C++ 2015 installed.

see screenshot below.[image]

Comment: So do you have that file somewhere or not?

Comment: I don't have it... I searched online for possible solution but I couldn't solve it. I went ahead to download the dll file but it popped another dll file missing . I ended up downloading 7 dll files before I stopped downloading them. Anyone experienced this error before? I'm using window8.1 64bits, python3. 4, django1. 9 and Postgresql9. 5

Answer (score 1):

These steps will fix windows installations:

- Start by upgrading to latest python (3.6), Django (2.x), postgres (10.x) and postgis (2.4.x).
- Run `python` to check if your **python** is 32 or 64 bit (It will be displayed on the screen).
- Install corresponding [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) (32 or 64 bit) into `C:\OSGeo4W` or `C:\OSGeo4W64`:

  - **Note:** Select Express Web-GIS Install and click next.
  - In the ‘Select Packages’ list, ensure that GDAL is selected; MapServer and Apache are also enabled by default, may be unchecked safely.
- Make sure the following is included in your Django's `settings.py`:

  ```
  import os
  if os.name == 'nt':
      import platform
      OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
      if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
          OSGEO4W += "64"
      assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
      os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
      os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
      os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
      os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
  ```
- Run `python manage.py check` to verify geodjango is working correctly.